# toString method Not Capitalizing Letters

Tags: java, string, methods, tostring

I'm learning Java for a class and one of the assignments I need to do is implementing String methods into my code. After prompting the user to set text, I used a toLowerCase() method and printed it. On another line, I used a toUpperCase() method and printed it. Both printed correctly but whenever I used the toString() method, it only my text in lowercase.

Here is my main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TalkerTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter some text: ");
        String words = input.nextLine();


        Talker talky = new Talker(words); 
        String yelling = talky.yell();
        String whispers = talky.whisper();

        System.out.println(talky);
        System.out.println("Yelling: " + yelling);
        System.out.println("Whispering: " + whispers);

    }
}
```

Here is my class with all my methods

```
public class Talker
{
    private String text;

    // Constructor
    public Talker(String startingText)
    {
        text = startingText;
    }

    // Returns the text in all uppercase letters
    // Find a method in the JavaDocs that
    // will allow you to do this with just
    // one method call
    public String yell()
    {
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        return text;
    }

    // Returns the text in all lowercase letters
    // Find a method in the JavaDocs that
    // will allow you to do this with just
    // one method call
    public String whisper()
    {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        return text;
    }

    // Reset the instance variable to the new text
    public void setText(String newText)
    {
        text = newText;
    }

    // Returns a String representatin of this object
    // The returned String should look like
    // 
    // I say, "text"
    // 
    // The quotes should appear in the String
    // text should be the value of the instance variable
    public String toString()
    {
        text = text;
        return "I say, " + "\"" + text + "\"";
    }
}
```

I apologize for the long paste and my bad English.

Comment: What do you think the point of `text = text` is in `toString`? It doesn't do anything

Comment: Always include the actual and expected output. Not just a description "not working". Show the exact output you get! And yes, your toString method just shows the text, without any uppercase?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your methods `yell()` and `whisper`, you also edit your variable `text`. In fact, before the line

```
    System.out.println(talky);
```

you have used the method `whisper` which make the variable `text` into lowercase.

You have to edit your code like this:

```
public String whisper()
    {
        return text.toLowerCase();
    }

public String yell()
    {
        return text.toUpperCase();
    }

public String toString()
    {
        return "I say, " + "\"" + text + "\"";
    }
```

Moreover, to be more precise, use the Java [keyword](https://www.guru99.com/java-this-keyword.html) `this` when you use the variable `text`! For example,

```
public Talker(String startingText)
    {
        this.text = startingText;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

It is because you modify the value of `text`. It will persist even after you return. You should not. Instead, directly return like this:

```java
String yell() {
    return text.toUpperCase();
}
```